# Response property issue

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have an Angular 7 application that calls an ASP.Net core MVC wep api.

The web api returns a HttpResponseMessage where I set the StatusCode and ReasonPhrase.

I have 2 Angular components that call 2 different web api methods.

When I am into the app.MemberRegistration.Component.ts logic calling the web api, I get an undefined property (Cannot read property 'reasonPhrase' of undefined). Basically not showing me the 'reason phrase' set in the web api controller. I do however get the StatusCode of 304 that is set in the controller if I do not reference the reason phrase in my alert. So I know it is going into that logic.

[image]

When I am into the app.Renewal.Component.ts logic calling the web api, I get the reason phrase set in the web api controller just fine along with the StatusCode of 200 that is set in the controller.

Why are the properties between the 2 different - i.e upper and lower case 1st character? They appear differently in the intellisense available to choose per component?

Here is the web api's RegisterMemberController code snip it.

```
   var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
   {
      // Status code: 304.
      StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotModified,
      ReasonPhrase = "Critical Error. In RegisterMemberController - 
      api/RegisterMember - POST. Executing the procedures in: MemberRegistrationConcrete/InsertMember()."
   };

   return response;
```

Here is the web api's RenewalController code snip it.

```
   var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
   {
      // Status code: 200.
      StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
      ReasonPhrase = "Renewed Successfully."
   };

   return response;
```

Here is the app.Renewal.Component.ts (it has ReasonPhrase):

[image]

Here is the app.MemberRegistration.Component.ts (it has reasonPhrase):

[image]

Comment: I don't typically use 304, but my understanding is that this tells the client agent (browser) that the request resource hasn't changed, so use the cached copy. Maybe you have an older cached version of the response with a case difference? Not sure why the case would be different. I would change the response to 200 and see if it then works, or maybe delete cache. This is just a shot in the dark since you don't seem to be getting any responses.

Comment: John, I choose the 304 to just differentiate the code path as originally 2 paths were passing the same code of 400. The code really has nothing to do with it. But thanks.